# How to Create Pixel Based Text Logo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, logo, pixel

I want to write 'SBS' in Pixel Art Style

SBS is a Software House, so that's why I want to make something that is related to computers or technology etc.

like this

[image]

or like this

[image]

I want to see how I can achieve these easily. Preferably a method that doesn't involve copying and pasting blocks around.

Also if you have any ideas  for the SBS logo please share.

Comment: Your samples seem to show two different problems which have different answers, and I wouldn't call the first "pixel-based". I think you need to make this question more specific.

Comment: Am I the only one finding the kerning of *INNOVATIONS* horrible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are planning to use photoshop for making your logo, here is how, I think, you can go for it:

1) create a new blank document, with your desired dimension.

2) Use any bold(thick) font and type "SBS".

3) Add stroke to the text, by double clicking the text layer, via Layer Styles.

4) Create a rectangular box (U), and duplicate it as many times as you require (right click on layer and click on duplicate).

5) Try to place the boxes inside the text. (I had suggested to keep a bold font because placing boxes will become easier that way.)

6) After placing all the boxes, you can simple remove/hide the text layer, and you will see a logo design like the one you are looking for.

P.S. You can always play with colors/sizes/layer styles to make your boxes look better.

Answer (score 2):

> Preferably a method that doesn't involve copying and pasting blocks
>   around.

Unfortunately you're going to need to do this work yourself. Not everything in this world is perfect and automated yet. While I'm sure there's some sort of software/action out there to achieve this, you'll have much more control and freedom over your logo if you do it by hand.

It may be a bit tedious, but design often requires you to sit down and just work through things, by hand.

Other answers have made great suggestions (such as typing the letters out and then placing blocks on top) and I would tell you to follow that advice. Make sure you use Illustrator over Photoshop though, that way you have a vector file and you can always easily edit/adjust your logo and size it up if need be.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a pixel based font style.

Such as : [Bitmap Fonts](http://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php)

than apply your imagination that how can you make your word stand out.

one thing you can do is write the text [SBS] then convert it into shapes and do some modifications.

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a thick font and then layer it with an image that has the effect you are looking for.  Use a layer clipping mask to apply the patterned image into your letters.